# D3.js seems to be converting Date to integers

Tags: d3.js

I'm having an issue where D3.js is forcing dates to convert to integers as it passes them to the axis function. This is breaking `d3.time.format` on my Axis. Basically I have:

```
axis.tickformat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

However this throws an error because when it tries to format the date it's being passed the integer value of the date instead of the original date object (my data set does have Date objects in it, I've checked).

Instead I have to do this:

```
format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")
axis.tickFormat(function(date) { format(new Date(date)) })
```

Which works but seems wrong and unnecessary. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: Some additional information:

The time.format function expects a Date object. However what appears to be happening is this is being coerced into a simple integer Number. d3.time.format uses functions like `Date.getYear()` for formatting so these result in undefined errors when called on the integer.

As stated passing everything through new Date() works, but it should be unnecessary since the original data set is in fact all dates.

The working example is running here: https://wealthbar.github.io/angular-d3/. However it is a bit complex and involved AngularJS as well.

Comment: Could you post your complete code please? `Date` objects are basically just integers, so this may be where your confusion is coming from.

Comment: The complete code is a fairly complex setup involving AngularJS but it is public. The working version of the relevant code is here: https://github.com/WealthBar/angular-d3/blob/master/src/angularD3/directives/axis.coffee#L47

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm coming across a similar issue..

Answer (score 0):

The return from `d3.time.format` is a function that accepts either a string (in which case it returns a `Date` object) or a `Date` object (in which case it returns a string). When you use `d3.time.format` as a parameter to `axis.tickformat()`, the tick formatter is going to pass the datum object to `d3.time.format`. You don't specify the format of your data, but most likely it's a number (milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970?) in which case it doesn't match the type of parameter `d3.time.format` is expecting.

In any case, there's nothing wrong with the second approach you outline.

Comment: Actually I believe date.time.format.parse is what accepts a string. Format accepts a Date. However for some reason the value that is being passed from the data is the date integer and not the Date object.

Comment: Sorry also I did specify the format of the data above when I said that all of the dates are actual Date objects and that I've double checked this is in fact the case. So essentially I'm calling new Date() on the data set originally when I created it, then I have to do it again before formatting it. Which is what is weird to me.